# Get target branch ref in Github Actions for PR that is [not] from a fork

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm trying to test a PR handling action on Github.

For that I'm creating a PR in my own repo and trying to use `${{ github.base_ref }}`, but it is empty.
This [help page](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables) says that `GITHUB_BASE_REF` is only available for PRs from forks.

Is there a way to get the target branch for a PR event, regardless of whether it is from a forked PR or not? Or a way to address the latter case specifically.

P.S. What I'm really trying to do is to get a list of changed files in the PR. What I have works for pushes but not for PRs:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.event.before }} ${{ github.sha }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work regardless of whether it's raised from a fork or not.

```
${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}
```

By the way, you can add a step in your workflow to dump the `github` context object to see all available properties.

```
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```